# Why are model IDs not preserved in the collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I set IDs to my models as follows:

```
var globalCounter = 0;
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.set('id', globalCounter);
        globalCounter += 1;
    }
});
```

Now I add a bunch of instances of `MyModel` to a collection:

```
var i, model;
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
myCollection = new MyCollection();

for(i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    model = new MyModel();
    myCollection.add(model);
}
```

The problem is that the IDs do not seem to be passed on:

```
console.log(myCollection.pluck('id')); // gives [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Why are the IDs of the models I add to my collection disappearing?

Comment: This code works for me; http://jsbin.com/ojonoh/1/ `// [0, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define globalCounter where define MyModel, but probably where you create the instance of MyModel globalCounter is not in the scope of your script.

It is like an "autoincrement" implemented on the FrontEnd, you could do this that I wrote you to prevent scope issues(the autoincrement key will be part of the "Model definition" like some kind of static var):

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    globalCounter : 0,
    initialize: function () {
        this.set('id', MyModel.prototype.globalCounter++);
    }
});
```